# Is this number, N, greater than Graham’s Number?

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers, number-comparison

So, using Knuth’s up-arrow notation, 
if 3 ↑ 3 = 3^3 and 3 ↑ ↑ 3 = 3 ↑ (3 ↑ 3) = 3 ↑ 27 = 3^27 
Then consider number N defined by Knuth's up-arrow notation: 
$$N = googolplex\uparrow^{googolplex} googolplex$$

> Is the number $N$ greater than Graham’s Number or is it even possible to determine this?

Comment: That number is incredibly ***tiny*** compared to Graham's number. Remember that Graham's number is $3\uparrow^k3$ where $k$ itself is the gigantically huge result of a "[tower](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/bf21d56674c30b0672d208fdd2566111c8f49dfa)" of chained arrow expressions; it's not hard to unpack the definition to see that by the fourth(?) level of the tower we've already gone well past your $N$. That said, I'm not totally sure that this question is appropriate for MSE *(just because of the danger of generating a flood of "how big is **this**?"-type questions)*.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: I thought what the OP intended is the number is $k\uparrow^k k,$ where $k = 10^{10^{100}} = \text{googleplex},$ which is much greater than Graham's number. Incidentally, whenever I see huge numbers used in the binary operation's argument, I know the person doesn't have much of an idea of how powerful these higher level operations are, since we may as well use $3$ or $4$ and increment the operation level by one or two to completely annihilate it. The OP may be interested in my old sci.math posts cited [in this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/74395/15780).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I intended to write k ↑(googleplex amount of times) k. Is this not the same as k ↑^k k. Or am I not understanding the “to the power of” notation in terms of Knuth’s up-arrow notation?

Comment: As I explain in this [4 March 2002 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/WBZ53faqft0/m/llkUkquLPA8J), depending on the reference used, Graham's number is either between $2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 61$ and $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 132$ or far, far beyond what you wrote (a googleplex up-arrows), so much so that it's difficult for us mortals to distinguish between the number itself and how many up-arrows are involved (in a way similar to: if $n = 10\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 10,$ then $10^n$ is "basically the same as" $n).$

Comment: @Noah Schweber: I was thinking that the non-Smorynski version of Graham's number involved something like $63$ or $64$ up-arrows, but this is not correct -- it's way, way beyond that, as you indicated.

Comment: Graham's number is defined as follows : $G_1:=3\uparrow^4 3$  , $G_{n+1}:=3\uparrow^{G(n)} 3$. Then Graham's number is $G_{64}$. Even $G_2$ is way beyond your number since $G_1$ is much much much larger than googolplex and your number is smaller than $3\uparrow^{googolplex+1} 3$

Comment: $G_n$ is strictly increasing and not only that. The magnitude of the next entry compared to the current one is unimaginable.